# Earlier fetched but cannot see the reports

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wanted to see the disbursed clients of particular month (application wise) and their location details fetched from the service vendor.

Seems like I am having problem in getting the details. I know the reason but I am not able to track it down by writing a proper query.

ContactID = Every customer will have a unique contactid

Applicationid = It is also unique but multiple application id can have in each contact id. Like customer can come and take the product and close it. Again he/she can come with new applicationid but same contactid.

Now I see the null value in some cases and in some cases I got the proper result. For the NULL value I knew these are those clients who have already taken the product and came back again.

Our service provider only fetch the service for the first time and give the details. There is no need of fetching it again and again.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNvby.png)
I have tried this

```
select top 100
    C.contactid,
    C.TSIApplicationId,
    PD.state
from [DH].[Customer] as C
inner join [DH].[parsed_details] as PD
    on C.ContactId = PD.ContactId
where C.availed = 1
    and C.CreatedOnMonth = '2023-04' 

and got the below mentioned output



|Contactid|TSIapplicationID|STATE|
|:--------|:--------------:|----:|
|B4248DE0-A289-45D0-A277|5DAC2DF9-CDF5-4837-93A6-611DF09E6DA3|NULL|
|62475FCF-5295-4959-8BD5-|99D2B3F7-4BA1-AC91-BC66C7C07252|NULL|
|540C5F51-B205-4F33-BEC6-|8068F070-46ED-880A-0E4C9DD98F93|NULL|
|29ED24B6-6E80-45CE-85BC-|BF4B6B85-4AE7-828E-BF08A41FD0D4|UTTAR PRADESH|
|111B62F0-2957-421A-810C-|F9C40D73-4D60-BB1A-D5EB28C72873|ASSAM|
|E190351A-4015-47A8-8146-|AA23E504-45DC-B5E7-E81DE54AF30E|NULL|





 

I wanted to get the location of the customer application wise even for the customer who have taken the product second time. The desired output should be


|Contactid|TSIapplicationID|STATE|
|:--------|:--------------:|----:|
|B4248DE0-A289-45D0-A277|5DAC2DF9-CDF5-4837-93A6-611DF09E6DA3|Bihar|
|62475FCF-5295-4959-8BD5-|99D2B3F7-4BA1-AC91-BC66C7C07252|Orissa|
|540C5F51-B205-4F33-BEC6-|8068F070-46ED-880A-0E4C9DD98F93|TN|
|29ED24B6-6E80-45CE-85BC-|BF4B6B85-4AE7-828E-BF08A41FD0D4|UTTAR PRADESH|
|111B62F0-2957-421A-810C-|F9C40D73-4D60-BB1A-D5EB28C72873|ASSAM|
|E190351A-4015-47A8-8146-|AA23E504-45DC-B5E7-E81DE54AF30E|MP|
```

Comment: `t1` and `t2` are poor table aliases. Choose something that makes sense, like `c` for `customers` and perhaps `pd` for `parsed_details`.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Note that most people here want sample table data _and_ the expected result as properly formatted text (no links, no images.)

Comment: Fixing the aliases while having a cutoff of a screenshot as the only details on how the data looks is equivalent of swiping the flours while the building is getting demolished

Comment: This is my first post...apologies for the errors. If anything else needed write down in the comment section i am actively seeking for the results

Comment: The data you show, is that the raw data? Or your desired results? You need to show both, first some sample data for both the relevant tables. Then the results you want to accomplish from your query (that matches the sample data). I can't tell which you are providing, but it doesn't appear to be all both.

Comment: I have done it, the output will be giving the value for each row instead of NULL values.

Comment: I don't get it, if the contactID is the same, why are you getting NULL values when you join parsed_details? There should only be one row per contact, and it shouldn't be NULL according to what you wrote. How should code fetch the non-null value?